# What's the parametric equation of a partial ellipse in 3D space with given major axis and minor axis and start point and end point?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, 3d, parametric

Consider a partial ellipse in 3D space with the following information:

1. majorAxis (a 3D vector, such as [1, 0, 0])
2. minorAxis (a 3D vector, such as [0, 1, 0])
3. startPoint (a 3D vector, such as [1, 0, 0])
4. endPoint (a 3D vector, such as [0, 0.5, 0])
5. centerPoint (a 3D vector, such as [0, 0, 0])
6. majorRadius (a scalar value, such as 1)
7. minorRadius (a scalar value, such as 0.5).

Then, how to find the parametric equation of this partial ellipse?

Answer (score 5):

It’s really no different that it would be in 2-D: if the center is $\mathbf c$ and the semiaxes are defined by the vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ (the lengths of these vectors are the half-axis lengths), then a parameterization of the ellipse is $\mathbf c+(\cos t)\mathbf u+(\sin t)\mathbf v$.

If you just need an arc of this ellipse, then you will have to find an appropriate interval for $t$. An easy way to do this is to map everything to the unit circle: Let $A = \small{\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf u&\mathbf v\end{bmatrix}}$ and let $M=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$. Then $\phi:\mathbf p\mapsto M(\mathbf v-\mathbf c)$ maps your ellipse to the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$ such that the major and minor axes are mapped to the coordinate axes. The above parameterization is simply the inverse image of the unit circle $(\cos t,\sin t)^T$, so by applying $\phi$ to the end points of the arc, you can compute suitable values of $t$ for them.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to find the interval of t. I tried the starting t as the rotation angle from the U to vector of (startPoint - centerPoint). But it doesn't work. What's the best way to find the interval of t?

Comment: @Hugoo As I wrote above, the easiest way is to map everything to the unit circle, where $t$ directly represents an angle. There’s a geometric construction that could be used, but it’s going to be more work, I think.

Comment: Starting from your formula, I have proposed a different formulation.

Comment: How are $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ related to the directions of the axis of the ellipse?

Comment: @user266148 The first paragraph of my answer seems pretty clear to me. Those two vectors, together with the center, are the semiaxes of the ellipse. In fact, they don’t even have to be the semiaxes: they can be any pair of conjugate radii.

Answer (score 2):

From the generic parametric equation

$$\mathbf x = \mathbf c+(\cos t)\mathbf u+(\sin t)\mathbf v$$

i.e.,

$$\mathbf x =\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{pmatrix}+\cos(t)\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{pmatrix}+\sin(t)\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\mathbf x =\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}u_1 \cos(t)+v_1 \sin(t)\\u_2 \cos(t)+v_2 \sin(t)\\u_3 \cos(t)+v_3 \sin(t)\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

given by @amd, let me give a a form that can be handy for manupulating arcs of 3D ellipses.

It suffices to know that any expression of the form $a \cos(t)+b \sin(t)$ can be written

$$a \cos(t)+b \sin(t)=n \cos(\alpha)\cos(t)+n \sin(\alpha)\cos(t)$$

for a certain $\alpha$, where $n$ is the norm of vector $\binom{a}{b}$ and $\alpha$ its polar angle. Otherwise said:

$$a \cos(t)+b \sin(t)=n \cos(t-\alpha)$$

Thus (1) becomes :

$$\mathbf x =\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}n_1 \cos(t-\alpha_1)\\n_2 \cos(t-\alpha_2)\\n_3 \cos(t-\alpha_3)\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

It remains to adapt the domain of variation of $t$. This ellipse looks to depend on 9 parameters. In fact $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are obtained apart. Let us now see how one can obtain say for the initial point adequate values for the 6 remaining parameters $n_1,n_2,n_3$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ ; setting for example $t=0$, one gets a first set of 3 equations ; then one must recall that $\mathbf u$ and  $\mathbf v$ are unit vectors (this gives 2 more equations) and are orthogonal (1 more equation). Thus we have 6 equations for 6 unknowns that should have a solution (we assume here a certain faisability ; but, to be honest, a discussion should take place here).